# input change on enter than blur triggers second change on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

having `<input name="foo" id="foo">` and change handler that blurs input for `change` triggered by <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
$('#foo').on('change', function(event) {
  $(document.body).append('<br>change called');
  var $target = $(event.target);
  if ($target.is(':focus')) {
    $(document.body).append('<br>input still in focus - calling blur');
    $target.blur();    
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/ciekawy/pen/oLqdNG?editors=1111

On Safari calling `blur` triggers additional `change` (while on Chrome not). I haven't found any reasonable solution to handle this behaviour. I'd rather not use timer nor flags to prevent second entry.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the `$target.blur()` there. The `change` event is called once the value of the input has changed (on blur/on enter, but only if the value has changed). When the user hits `enter` the `change` event is triggered (to check if value really changed), and after that change - the browser will move the `focus` from that element.

Comment: on `Enter` there is only `change` event and no `blur`. Inside the `change` handler in fact I'd like to decide whether to accept the new value and thus blur the input or leave it focused when i.e. another change is required.